# java.time ::toString(String pattern) method missing

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z";

    // joda-time
    DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
    System.out.println(dt.toString(pattern));

    // java.time
    ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(ldt.toString(pattern)); // doesn't exist
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
}
```

joda-time classes (`DateTime`, `LocalDate`, etc) included a `toString` method that accepts a String of the format you wanted. This was a very handy method. Yet, the java-8 implementation omits this method. Instead, you need to call `format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)`.

A small gripe, sure. But my question is: **is there any reason this was omitted from java.time**? Converting my applications from joda-time to java.time will be that much more difficult because of this small omission. But, I'm ok with it if there's a logical reason. Not that you are here to assuage my concerns, but I thought I'd ask just in case.

Edit: to the close-voters, this is not an opinion-based question. Anyone who is familiar with the inner-workings of joda-time/java.time and their motivations to develop in certain ways is qualified to answer the question, even if they never do.

Comment: Note that joda-time is still a hell of a library and there's no real reason (unless you need to save 500KB of storage of the `.jar`) to switch.

Comment: Is the primary purpose of `java.time`, then, to prevent new projects from necessitating joda-time?

Comment: @ryvantage The author of `java.time` is the author of JodaTime. So I'd say that `java.time` is the spiritual successor of JodaTime.

Comment: @ryvantage TBH, it kind of is an opinion-based question because there is no real answer (unless the actual authors chime in). We're simply speculating.

Comment: Exactly why I asked the question: if the same author wrote both, then he must've had a reason for omitting the method. I'm just wondering why.

Comment: The primary purpose of `java.time` is to improve date handling in Java because `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` were terrible. I don't think Java is trying to compete with joda.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, even if the question never gets answered because the only qualified answerers never answer the question, that doesn't make it an opinion-based question. I'm not soliciting your speculation.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Not really - java.time is a general purpose date time library which does not have as many specialised methods as joda time.

Comment: @assylias Ah, my mistake then. I was going off what I read years ago about JSR-310.

Comment: Stephen Colebourne is on SO. I've seen him comment here before, so he might weigh in. My guess would be that they didn't want to override toString and they may not have wanted to parse/compile the format string each time.

Comment: @ryvantage My point is simply that until the actual author chimes in, we're simply speculating. We can make a guess, but that's about it. My opinion is that it is to make the API cleaner.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, I understand what you're saying, but although I may just be spinning my wheels with you, I'll repeat: I'm not soliciting your speculation. Even if the only qualified answerers never answer, it doesn't make it opinion-based. There is an answer, even if it never surfaces.

Comment: Obvious advantage of JSR-310-approach is promoting reusing existing `DateTimeFormatter`-objects instead of creating new ones. For sake of convenience, this might be seen as regression compared with Joda. And if you also use features like intervals or date-time-periods with `PeriodType` then you should better not replace JodaTime by JSR-310 (here less features while in other areas more features).

Comment: Ok, well by this comment thread I can see another question emerging - which is better: joda-time or java.time? Do they serve different purposes or are they trying to accomplish the same goal? Wouldn't the same author of joda-time write a library that is superior to the old one? Maybe I should start a new question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting question. Joda-Time and java.time (JSR-310) have different design centres - Joda-Time is an open source library, but java.time is an extension to the JDK. One practical implication is more pressure on method count, which was a factor here.

The method in question in Joda-Time is one of four:

- `toString()`
- `toString(DateTimeFormatter dtf)`
- `toString(String pattern)`
- `toString(String pattern, Locale loc)`

The first is a standard method in Java and so is included by default. The formatter-based method is a convenience as you could just use the formatter itself. The two pattern-based methods are a further convenience, as they simply create a formatter.

Note however that the pattern-based method requires two variants, one with and one without the locale, whereas the formatter embeds the locale internally (thus no need for a method variant). The need for the extra locale method weighed heavily when considering JSR-310.

An additional consideration is caching/performance. Joda-Time has a cache of patterns to formatters, to avoid re-parsing patterns like "yyyy-MM-dd". Such a cache was less welcome in the JDK and it was desirable to find a way to not have a cache.

The recommended approach for formatters with java.time is to assign them to static variables. The new formatter is thread-safe (unlike the old one) so this works well. In addition, defining a constant for the formatter means that the parsing of the pattern occurs only once - the constant stores the internal data structure ready to format/parse.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z");
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.now();
  System.out.println(ldt.format(FORMATTER);
}
```

Finally, the method in JSR-310 was originally called `toString(DateTimeFormatter)`. Internal reviews within Oracle recommended renaming the method to `format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

Comment: So, practicality (less methods, no caching) vs convenience, practicality wins out for the JDK. Thanks! Good to hear straight from the source.

Answer (score 1):

Anything I say is speculation since you would have to talk to the authors of the new date-time API to actually find out.

I am guessing they decided to use the formatter since it is more semantically appropriate and more in line with what you are *actually* trying to do: format a date for a specific locale. Even though `toString` takes in a pattern, the signature `toString(String)` is not exactly intuitive. Furthermore, it is probably better to have a dedicated method that handles date formatting, than overloading `Object#toString`. It definitely makes for a cleaner API.

Again, as I said, this is speculation so to get the real answer you would have to go to the source. But if I was doing something like this, these would be my reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The decisive advantage of the `format` alternative is that one may share the single DateTimeFormatter (this is not the old unsharable unthreadsafe DateFormatter).

API quotation:

> A formatter created from a pattern can be used as many times as
>   necessary, it is immutable and is thread-safe.

Not having both, is a matter of cleanliness in API design.

So this API lends one to write:

```
final DateTimeFormatter DTF =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"));
...
System.out.println(ldt.format(DTF));
```